# Google maps changing a route given by a link

Tags: google-maps

I created the directions using https://www.google.com/maps my PC. The directions are not the shortest route. I've sent the link via Facebook Messenger:

https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fdir%2FKooskia%2C%2BIdaho%2BCounty%2C%2BID%2FFog%2BMountain%2C%2BID%2B83539%2F%4046.0870642%2C-115.6040729%2C12z%2Fdata%3D!4m19!4m18!1m10!1m1!1s0x54a099a8e938ec4b%3A0x1a26a25f8e52a6b2!2m2!1d-115.9779189!2d46.1448942!3m4!1m2!1d-115.676752!2d46.102913!3s0x54a09fc76bce9d25%3A0x54e8e74decd35d79!1m5!1m1!1s0x535f46b661626efb%3A0xddb17339bfa227d!2m2!1d-115.236512!2d46.0932474!3e0&h=AT3h0DE3UQ4wWecBOlI0Mr6-t_ry6N3SZ02I9_vrNtno2dbHaDM8y26hkRtpq_gqHflsPsrZYk1ENemba7z-JkFdZanus04llDAzzlduyOsBSDNS7viQ5N8NaT_Tng

When I open it on Android 11 phone the last part of this URL is trimmed:

`&h=AT3h0DE3UQ4wWecBOlI0Mr6-t_ry6N3SZ02I9_vrNtno2dbHaDM8y26hkRtpq_gqHflsPsrZYk1ENemba7z-JkFdZanus04llDAzzlduyOsBSDNS7viQ5N8NaT_Tng`

and Maps app displays a different route. When I try the trimmed or a full length link on my PC in Chrome the original route is displayed correctly. How to make Android display the original route?

Comment: I just tried opening the link on Chrome PC and looks like [it's Facebook who trimmed the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G58qq.png). Also, I got 2 different results on Chrome PC; 1) the trimmed Facebook link goes to Fog Mountain, Idaho 83539, United States by car, 2) the original URL goes to NF-319, Idaho 83539, USA with recommended travel mode.

Comment: @AndrewT. I had the same results with both links on my PC. To fix the problem on Android, I chose a named waypoint instead of dragging the route with a mouse: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Kooskia,+Idaho+County,+ID/NF-286,+Idaho+83539/Big+Fog+Saddle,+Idaho